# How to get row id on button click?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to make an shopping cart by using jsp. I need to get id from a row to add another table using that id. I have table created and buttons placed. What kind of method should I create or what should I do at all? Thanks...

I want to run this sql command to update the cart : "`insert into users.cart (Name, Price) select Name, Price from users.product where id = (...);`

This is a part of my jsp file that i need to use that button to get id

```
<tr>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>ProductName</b></td>
<td><b>Description</b></td>
<td><b>Price</b></td>
</tr>
<%

try{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","");
    Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users.product"); 

    out.println("<h1 align = \"center\">Start Shopping:</h1><br>");

    while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>

<td><%=rs.getString("Name") %></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("Description") %></td>
<td><%=rs.getInt("Price") %></td>
<td><input type = "button" value = "Add to cart"></td>

</tr>

<% 
}

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<a>` tag to pass `id` to your `jsp` page where your query to `insert` is there like below :

```
 <td>
 <!-- here you are passing your id=somevalue to yourjsp page-->
   <a href="yourjsp.page?id=<%=rs.getString("id") %>">
    <input type = "button" value = "Add to cart">
   </a>
 </td>
```

And to get above `id` you can do like below :

```
   String id=request.getParameter("id");//getting id passed in url also you can convert this id to int
```

Passed `id` in your query and then `redirect` to your `jsp` page.